# MySQL Error 1064?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

Hello all I'm trying to do the following insert to my database however every time I try it it fails with a vender error of 1064. I have two double fields for the lat and long, and an integer id. Could someone tell me what's going on here?

```
INSERT INTO LatLong (lat, long) VALUES (51.53087375, -0.26259048);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The column `long` is a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). Surround it with backticks to fix the error:

```
INSERT INTO `LatLong` (`lat`, `long`) VALUES (51.53087375, -0.26259048);
```

It's a good practice, but not necessary, to surround all of your column and table names with backticks as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! As soon as it will let me mark this as an answer I will. I've struggled with this for a couple hours at least I would've never thought about it being a reserve word.

Comment: Backticks; annoying little characters that provide so much relief! Glad I could help =]